# How to force local variables in ruby to work with included code parts?

Tags: ruby, sketchup

How to force local variables in ruby to work with included code parts? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
def q1
name = "123"
include xxx
end

def q2
name = "456"
include xxx
end


def xxx
@dialog.execute_script(name+'()')
end
```

But this method works for instance variables only..

upd. for now in works with xxx(name) method, thanks everyone!

Comment: Local variables do not leak through scopes in ruby, and this is _good_, nobody needs them to leak. Also, one cannot include a method.

Comment: But any ideas how to avoid code repetition?

Comment: Call XXX, passing name as a parameter.

Comment: @dem what is your code supposed to do? Can you show a working example _with_ code repetition?

Comment: Did you consider the `xxx` method to except an argument named `name` and call `xxx(name)` in `q1` and `q2` instead of `include xxx`?

Comment: @mudasobwa, @Stefan thanks! 
`
def q1
name = "123"
xxx(name)
end

def q2
name = "456"
xxx(name)
end

def xxx(name)
@dialog.execute_script(name+'()')
end
`

Comment: I would like to try it, but what is @dialog?

Comment: @iGian its UI dialog window in Sketchup

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you really just want to pass name as parameter into method xxx:

```
def q1
    name = 123
    xxx(name)
end

def xxx(name)
    @dialog.execute_script(name+'()')
end
```

Now, keep in mind, the parameter of method xxx could be called anything, it is not connected to the name of the local variable in method q1. It doesn't know anything about the scope of method q1.